# Merging apps on Google Play and App Store

Tags: android, ios, merge, google-play, app-store

I have a client for whom I have made three apps for different regions (App 1, App2, App3).

Now the client changed his strategy and instead of having a different brand for every region he wants just one global brand which also means one app. He obviously doesn't want to lose the users of the three old apps in the process so my question is: can I somehow merge all these apps into one on Google Play and Apple Store?

I couldn't find sufficient information anywhere. All I could think of was to update all three with a new package but that would mean that three apps (now with the same name and same everything) remain in the stores, which would probably result in deletion.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thank you guys. I was afraid this is going to be the way to go about it but I was still hoping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Comment: I am voting to keep the question because it's a software question (I have read the post). Answer is targeted at providing general guidance on app mergers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should tell all the  users of 3 applications by notification that they need to download new application and their data will be transferred into the new application.

Answer (score 0):

While Prashant Jaiswal has already answered it, let me elaborate it a bit.

Step-1

Provide an update to each of your 3 apps that shows an overlay with a message saying that **We have a brand new version the app and current version of the app is going to be obsolete. Please install the new app from playstore**

Step-2

If there are any local databases associated with your app, then make a provision to update all the user data to server as a backup which they can retrieve again from the new app.

Step-3

If your app has social media login associated with your app, then it will no longer be continued, since changing the package name will result in creation of new app, so you have to make necessary changes in your server to handle the social media login.

step-4

Make the provision to accommodate the changes of step-1 to step-3 in your existing apps so that the migration can be taken place, and once user clicks on the install new version, begin your migration process before redirecting user to the play store.

step-5

Then use this link for Android [Implicit intent to uninstall application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868460/implicit-intent-to-uninstall-application) to uninstall your existing apps once the new app is downloaded and follow something similar for iOS part.

**final step**

All the above steps I mentioned by considering the general app design, there might be few more things that you have to consider based on the complexity of your app and its interaction with the servers

> Just so that you know, you can not merge the three apps directly at
>   playstore. The only way to merge the apps is create a merged app and
>   redirect the users.

Comment: As to step 5: YOu do not answer for iOS. This question asks about Google Play AND Apple App Store. The link you gave only covers android.

Comment: Yes @LunarWatcher , cos I am Android Developer, but I think the person who can create 6 apps (3 for android and 3 for iOS) will be smart enough to find out the iOS link on his own.

Comment: Don't you then think that person who is smart enough to create 6 apps(3 for ios 3 for android) also is smart enough to find the Android link on h*s own? You have to consider anyone else who has the same issue with either iOS, android or both. Remember that Stackoverflow is also about creating universal answers that can be applied to the same issue, even if presets are different. This question covers android and iOS, and in my opinion, all answers should reflect on that and try to answer as good as possible while covering both platforms

Comment: I am an Android developer too, and I have covered both Apple store and Google Play. If you can't answer both, you shouldn't answer a question that covers both.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @LunarWatcher, As per my knowledge, its you who have copied my answer. Next, I don't want to mislead anyone by posting something I am not sure of (iOS part), last but not the least, my whole answer is Universal, and the uninstall part is an example but not the answer.

Comment: look at the time elapsed since answered. If anything, you copied mine(because my answer came before yours). (At this time, mine was posted 24 minutes ago, yours 15 minutes ago)

Comment: @LunarWatcher I am not sure but do you know that stack overflow uses source control to timestamp each changes you make? If you know what I mean.

Comment: Yes I am. And yes it does. But if you look at all three answers, the content is basically the same: tell the users to install a different app. It is how it is elaborated(or not elaborated) that defines that they are two different questions. you elaborated in one direction, I in a different. ANd if you are to accuse me of copying your answer, first think about this: DIdn't you basically copy the content of Prashant's answer? I am not discussing this further with you, if you feel like accusing me, raise a flag on my answer.

Comment: stop this quarrel we have answered let the owner decide>

Comment: Well I clearly specified that I am elaborating @prashant's answer, and I did give him upvote too.

Comment: Someone has downvoted you answer again @PrashantJaiswal , you can check your points, you will have +10 -2